# Split parts of string to variables or into array

Tags: javascript, slice

Just out of curiosity, I want to know if there is a way to shorten this code. Every idea is accepted.

- I'm trying to make the code as small in characters as possible

```
const prefix = 'b!',
command = me.content.replace(RegExp(prefix + '\\s'), prefix)
 .slice(prefix.length).split(/\s/)[0],
content = me.content.replace(RegExp(prefix + '\\s'), prefix)
 .slice(prefix.length + command.length).trim(),
args = content.split(/\s/);
```

**me.content.replace(RegExp(prefix + '\s'), prefix)** is repeated in my code, is there a way to shorten it without creating another variable?

**input:** 'b! ban @SomeUser for breaking the rules'

- There may be one or more spaces between the prefix and the command (b! Ban) or not (b! Ban). That's why I replace it. Also, the prefix is ​​a variable, I added it as a constant as an example.

**expected output:**
command: 'ban',
content: '@SomeUser for breaking the rules',
args: [ '@SomeUser', 'for', 'breaking', 'the', 'rules' ]

Comment: Why? You want a smaller code in characters? Why not create a variable to reuse the repeated piece of code?

Comment: Could you provide an input string and the desired output?

Comment: Instead of focusing on making your code shorter, you should consider not repeating yourself which can make your code shorter.

Comment: I just don't understand why you try to replace `b!\\s` with `b!` but anyways it's not used in any of your string results - too much fuss for no gain whatsoever. Could you rephrase what is your task exactly?

Comment: If it's truly characters you're trying to save, then try using a minifier such as https://javascript-minifier.com/.  Wrap the code in a function so that it knows it can rename variables.  Normally people don't worry about optimizing characters though.

Comment: Yeah, you could make your variable just one character each /s

Answer (score 1):

```js
const str = "b! ban @SomeUser for breaking the rules";
const [m, cmd, cont] = str.match(/^b!\s+(\S+)\s+(.+)/);


console.log(cmd);
console.log(cont);
// console.log(cont.split(/\s+/))
```

Example and description on [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/PGIbBE/2)
PS, when splitting by *space* use `/\s+/` to treat consecutive spaces  as one.
The above is given your string always starts `^` with a `b!`  *"command"*.

If you also want to get the `@user` :

```js
const str = "b! ban @SomeUser for breaking the rules";
const [m, cmd, user, reason] = str.match(/^b!\s+(\S+)\s+(@\S+)\s+(.+)/);

console.log(cmd);
console.log(user);
console.log(reason);
```

Example and description on [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/PGIbBE/3/)

Answer (score 0):

you can do that :

```
const 
  myfunc  = ( prefix, adding) => me.content.replace(RegExp(prefix + '\\s'), prefix).slice(prefix.length +adding)  
, command = myfunc('b!',0).split(/\s/)[0]
, content = myfunc('b!', command.length).trim()
, args    = content.split(/\s/)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this shorter:

```js
const prefix = 'b!',
  [command, content] = (_ => {
    return ([
      _.slice(prefix.length).split(/\s/)[0],
      _.slice(prefix.length + command.length).trim()
    ]);
  })(me.content.replace(RegExp(prefix + '\\s'), prefix)),
  args = content.split(/\s/);
```